# Uniform integrability and convergence in mean question

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let the sequence $\left\{ \left| X_n - X \right|^r \right\}$ be uniformly
integrable for $r > 0$. This means that $E \left[ \left| X_n - X \right|^r 1
\left\{ \left| X_n - X \right|^r > a \right\} \right] \xrightarrow{a
\rightarrow \infty} 0$, uniformly in $n$.

I would like to understand a proof that $X_n \xrightarrow{L_r} X$ as $n
\rightarrow \infty$, meaning that $E \left| X_n - X \right|^r \xrightarrow{n
\rightarrow \infty} 0$.

Fix $\varepsilon > 0$
\begin{eqnarray*}
  E \left| X_n - X \right|^r & = & E \left[ \left| X_n - X \right|^r 1 \left\{
  \left| X_n - X \right|^r \leqslant \varepsilon \right\} \right] + E \left[
  \left| X_n - X \right|^r 1 \left\{ \left| X_n - X \right|^r > \varepsilon
  \right\} \right]\\
  & \leqslant & \varepsilon + E \left[ \left| X_n - X \right|^r 1 \left\{
  \left| X_n - X \right|^r > \varepsilon \right\} \right]
\end{eqnarray*}
Now if I could conclude from here that
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} E \left| X_n - X \right|^r \leqslant
   \varepsilon $$
then that would prove it.
The problem is the second term on the left hand side of the inequality goes to zero only as
$\varepsilon$ gets large. How is it possible to proceed from here?

**Edit:** What are the consequences of adding the assumption $X_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} X$
here? (It is a bit stronger than the suggestion in the comment below.)

Comment: You need the additional hypothesis that $X_n \to X$ in measure for this implication to be true.  It is certainly not the case that any family of uniformly integrable functions converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question is tagged (probability-theory), I assume the underlying space of finite measure. Let $Y_n:=|X-X_n|^r$; we assume that $Y_n\to 0$ in probability. Then 
$$E[Y_n]\leqslant E[Y_n\chi_{\{Y_n\leqslant R\}}]+\sup_{k\in\Bbb N}E[Y_k\chi_{\{Y_k\geqslant R\}}].$$
A consequence of the dominated convergence theorem is that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} E[Y_n\chi_{\{Y_n\leqslant R\}}]=0$ for each $R$, which gives, for each $R>0$, 
$$\limsup_{n\to +\infty}E[Y_n]\leqslant \sup_{k\in\Bbb N}E[Y_k\chi_{\{Y_k\geqslant R\}}].$$
We conclude using uniform integrability assumption.

Comment: Thanks for this short, elegant and simple proof. It's great!